# Default Button doesn't cause JFormattedTextField to commit current edit

Tags: java, swing, dialog, focus

I was wondering whether the way I expect the `JFormattedTextField` to work in combination with a default button is correct. When editing the value of a `JFormattedTextField`, you usually want to commit the value and then use it, this usually happens on `focusLost` or sometimes when the `ActionListener` is manually triggered. Now, if such a text field is inside of a `JDialog` which has a `DefaultButton` defined, triggering the default button with Ctrl+Enter will not cause the currently focused `JFormattedTextField` to trigger it's `focusLost` event.

Now, I see two solutions for this:

1. Manually make sure all inupt fields are in a comitted (or reverted) state
2. Use a `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater` in the `ActionListener` of the default button

However, both of these seem dirty, especially the first one, as it's not very easy to extend said dialog without forgetting to handle the components. The second one is rather undesirable imo because more `invokeLater`s usually mean more code that's harder to debug.

Is there a better way of solving this?

EXAMPLE:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DefaultButton
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField();
    field.setValue( "HELLO" );

    JButton defaultButton = new JButton( "Default" );
    defaultButton.addActionListener( __ ->
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( frame, "You've chosen: " + field.getValue() );
    } );
    frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton( defaultButton );

    JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
    panel.add( field, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    panel.add( defaultButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    frame.add( panel );

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

Comment: Got an [mcve] so we can test this out?

Comment: Yeah, i'll add one to the question.

Comment: OK so I got your example code and it runs.  What is the problem?  What do you want to be different?  The code appears to work correctly, which is the part that you don't like?

Comment: Like said, if you enter text and directly hit ctrl+enter, the button doesn't trigger commitEdit and the value is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when the `JFormattedTextField` has input focus and you activate the `defaultButton`, the `JFormattedTextField` does not lose focus and therefore the value is not committed.

Refer to [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).
Here is a quote:

> **A formatted text field's text and its value are two different properties, and the value often lags behind the text.**
> The *text* property is defined by the `JTextField` class. This property always reflects what the field displays. The *value* property, defined by the `JFormattedTextField` class, might not reflect the latest text displayed in the field. While the user is typing, the text property changes, but the value property does not change until the changes are *committed*.

I see two possible solutions (although I imagine there are more).
In the `actionPerformed()` method, either call `getText()` rather than `getValue()`, or call `commitEdit()` before calling `getValue()`, i.e.

```java
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( frame, "You've chosen: " + field.getText() );
```

or

```java
try {
    field.commitEdit();
}
catch (java.text.ParseException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You've chosen: " + field.getValue());
```

### EDIT

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DefaultButton
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField();
    field.setValue( "HELLO" );

    JButton defaultButton = new JButton( "Default" );
    defaultButton.addActionListener( __ ->
    {
        KeyboardFocusManager kfm = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        if (kfm.getFocusOwner() == field) {
            kfm.focusNextComponent();            
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( frame, "You've chosen: " + field.getValue() ));
    } );
    frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton( defaultButton );

    JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
    panel.add( field, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    panel.add( defaultButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    frame.add( panel );

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

Concentrate on method `actionPerformed()`. If the `JFormattedTextField` currently has the focus then force the focus to move to the next component. Regardless of which component has the keyboard focus, wrap the displaying of the `JOptionPane` in a `invokeLater()` call.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to avoid this solution, is that there might be more than one field. If you now add a new one, the developer needs to know that another manual commit has to be added.

Comment: I'll just do this for now. It's a bit crazy, but it'll do. Thanks.